# issues in working with python and excel xlrd xlwt

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt

I have an excel sheet im working with in Python. I want to be able to copy the current sheet to a new workbook, but without certain rows based on what their values are. For example if I have a sheet that list 10 peoples first names, last names, and ages, I want to copy this sheet to another workbook but only want to include the people under the age of 25. How would I got about this? If possible I would rather just delete those rows from the original sheet but after hours of reading and searching google it seems there isn't a built in function in xlrd or xlwt to delete rows or columns.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer

Comment: Why not gather all of the important information in the script and then spit it all out into your new sheet in the other workbook? Like you said, xlwt doesn't play well with deleting rows and columns.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm trying to do, but I want to copy the sheet minus the info I don't need rather than creating a new sheet because im working with a sheet that has thousands of rows and columns and the formatting of the original sheet is rather extensive. if I create a new sheet I would have to do a lot of page formatting to make the new page look like the old one.

Comment: The `xlutils` module is a handy library that works with `xlrd` and `xlrwt` - you may wish to look at whether you can do something with that and the `filter` system: http://pythonhosted.org/xlutils/filter.html